# If $X_n \ \xrightarrow{P}\ X$ and $|X_n|\leq c$, then $|X|\leq c$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $X_n$ a sequence of random variables such that $X_n \ \xrightarrow{P}\ X$ and there exists some $c>0$ such that $\forall n, |X_n|\leq c$. Then $|X|\leq c$ a.s.

This looks very simple but I'm having trouble dealing with this statement. I've tried bounding $P(|X|>c)$ by writing $|X|>c\implies |X-X_n|+|X_n|>c \implies |X-X_n| \geq c-|X_n| $ but this doesn't lead anywhere...

Comment: There'd exist a $d > c$ such that $P(\lvert X\rvert \geqslant d) > 0$ otherwise.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for the nudge, very helpful.

Comment: Another argument is that $X_n \xrightarrow{P} X$ implies that there is a subsequence $(X_{n_k})$ with $X_{n_k} \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} X$. (Use Borel-Cantelli)

Comment: @DanielFischer yeah that's a nice argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Daniel Fischer's hint:

If we don't have $|X|\leq c$ a.s, then $0<P(|X|>c)=P(\bigcup_{n} |X|>c+\frac 1n)=\lim_nP(|X|>c+\frac 1n)$, so there is some $m$ such that $P(|X|>c+\frac 1m) > 0$.

Note that $|X|>c+\frac 1m\implies |X-X_n|+|X_n|>c+\frac 1m \implies |X-X_n| \geq c+\frac 1m-|X_n|\geq \frac 1m$, hence $$0 < P(|X|>c+\frac 1m) \leq P(|X-X_n| \geq \frac 1m)$$

This contradicts $X_n \ \xrightarrow{P}\ X$.